# Where do the IIS server variables SERVER_NAME and HTTP_HOST come from?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, iis-7.5

Our ASP.NET application is not working at a customer installation because ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] and ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] return the string "Arcplan".

URLs which we build on the server are then incorrect (we use Request.Url.Authority which appears to use these ServerVariables internally).

The value "Arcplan" stored in the ServerVariables does not correspond to the name of the server or web site or anything that I can find. Maybe the computer was renamed and it used to be called Arcplan?

Does anyone know where IIS gets these values from? Are they stored in a config file somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL Rewrite configuration module if that thing has been set there.

Follow this link for more info:[setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables)

Comment: The URL Rewrite module is not installed

Comment: Ideally, HTTP_HOST is the name of the Web server. This may or may not be the same as SERVER_NAME depending on type of name resolution you are using on your Web server (IP address, host header). And SERVER_NAME is server's host name, DNS alias, or IP address as it would appear in self-referencing URLs.

Comment: "The Server's host name" - where is this? The Computer Name has a different value to that which is given by the SERVER_NAME IIS variable.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide some environment setup details?? Are you using any Apache server as well in front of IIS?? By, SERVER_NAME it would be DNS mapping with server IP@ or server config file which are most probable areas from where this variable can be set.

Comment: There is no apache. IIS 7.5 running on Windows 7. I don't know where to look for server config files - and this is a customer installation. We have changed our code now to avoid this problem. We were using it to build an absolute URL for static images on the server, but will now build relative urls. This will hopefully be more robust. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Have u checked if PHP is enabled on IIS??